# Xcode debugger messing with input

Tags: c, xcode

I'm writing a simple tokenizer in C and when I use the Xcode console to run my code and give input to my lexer, sometimes it's adding weird characters onto the end of my input.

**Here's an input that sometimes gets extra characters added onto it**

The input is on the line starting with (>>) and the data I print from the buffer is below it. You can see extra characters "\357 \234 1" somehow made their way into the buffer.

```
>> 2147483618
num read: 14
2 1 4 7 4 8 3 6 1 8 \357 \234 1
```

I thought it was an overflow problem, but it only happens when I run my code through the Xcode debugger.

**Here's what happens when I just use the Terminal to execute my code**

```
>> 2147483618
num read: 11
2 1 4 7 4 8 3 6 1 8
```

Here's my C code for reading in characters from the user:

```
for (;;) {
    char *buff = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

    // Max number of characters to read
    size_t num_to_read = 0;

    // Number of characters actually read
    size_t num_read = 0;

    num_read = getline (&buff, &num_to_read, stdin);
    printf("num read: %d\n", num_read);

    // Code to print out the buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < num_read; i++) {
        if (buff[i] == '\0')
            break;
        printf("%c ",buff[i]);
    }

    free(buff);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: The code is fine as far as I can tell (up to incorrect format specifier for `size_t`). The problem is likely in the console.

Comment: BTW, then you pass an allocated buffer to `getline`, the `num_to_read` should contain it's size. Check it's docs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for your help, I think I read when `num_to_read` is 0, you can pass a buffer of any size.

Comment: The `getline` needs to know if it should `realloc` the buffer or not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok, thanks for that, I've changed my code. Hasn't fixed the console bug unfortunately though.